# Containing jQuery into one container/section/div

Tags: html, jquery, css, responsive

I'm plugging in and testing some jQuery to my Cargo Collective site:

https://lisle.cargo.site/

Basically I've been playing round with this mouse-tracking jQuery effect which I love, but I cannot get the script to stay contained into one section of the site. As you scroll down the page, the image follows the mouse all the way through the journey.

Current code below.

Ideally I would love the effect to be contained to just the top VH/VW, then dis-engage as user passes the scroll point of the container.
I've tried wrapping in a div tag, then adjusting the height etc but to no avail.....

Any help would genuinely genuinely be much appreciated as always.
Thanks a bunch guys and hope you're all safe.

L

```js
$(document).on("mousemove", function(event) {
  $("img.lisle").css("width", event.pageX)
  $("img.lisle").css("height", event.pageY)

  $("img.stroke").css("width", $(window).width() - event.pageX)
  $("img.stroke").css("height", event.pageY)
})
```

```css
img {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100v%;
}

img. lisle {
  top: 0 !important;
  left: 0 !important;
}

img.stroke {
  top: 0 !important;
  right: 0 !important;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://freight.cargo.site/t/original/i/52942d135a28c76f77ec1127ef9a8d14d2df813d5f16575bdd381101d8097937/LisleA_Stretch.png" class="lisle" style="width: 1432px; height: 846px;">

<img src="
    https://freight.cargo.site/t/original/i/0292f819549959a5b1390d6d3c07c7853f8e95782e81450d62250dfd0b912a3e/test-stroke.png" class="stroke" style="width: 88px; height: 846px;">
```

Comment: Attach the `mousemove` listener to the section of the site you want it to affect instead of attaching it to `document`.

Comment: Hi and Welcome to SO. Please use a Code snippet (ctrl + m) the next time you want to include code into your quesion or an anwser. Also make sure to code clean. You had a messed up HTML mark up (`<img> src="..." > class=" ... >`) which is invalid HTML. The source `src` has to be included in the image tag same as the class. Cleaning up all the coding mistakes aswell as your "formatting"  to be valid code lines tooked me a while. Also please use the right terms. You kept mentioning Javascript while you use jQuery.

Comment: Thank you sir! very much –  OK that definitely makes sense, I just did a little research on that....but could you give me a very quick example of how I would go about naming this? I'm not sure how to call it or attach to my top section/page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

uff that broke my monitor :D, try it like this. But add unique id to the element.

```
$('.page_container').on("mousemove", function(event) {
  $("img.lisle").css("width", event.pageX)
  $("img.lisle").css("height", event.pageY)

  $("img.stroke").css("width", $(window).width() - event.pageX)
  $("img.stroke").css("height", event.pageY)
})
```

Comment: haha – right!
This is amazing – thank you brother, honestly! It's a little glitchy now it seems on tracking of the mouse....not sure why but if you have any other suggestions would love to hear them...gonna have a little look-up now, but genuinely thanks again

Comment: try putting the id="onMouseMove" to page_container element

Comment: Yup tried that too – it actually just tracks mouse when you go fairly slowly – you can snap off the iamge, then latch back on to pick up the tracking again. Kinda works for me tbh – for now. Thanks once again mate, hope you're having a great day! L

Comment: i copied your code (i hope thats ok) so u can test it putting it on page_container it works fine. Check here http://main.fluidsoftapps.com/test.php

Comment: OK mate I'm actually really embarrassed.....I actually thought I understood what you meant, but it looks like I don't....I'm sorry! I just went through all your code to look for the change, and your answer too but I cant work out how to implement your suggested change....can you walk me through how to switch up to the change? I'm sorry mate! thanks a tonne though....L

Comment: remove the div that u added with id="onMouseMove". Put the same id on the element with class="page_container" and data-id="18266728". should look like this <div data-container="page" class="page_container" local-style="18266728" data-id="18266728" id="onMouseMove">

Comment: ahhhh really don't know why mine isnt as responsive as yours...just spent an age comparing and trying out other stuff – I tried what you mentioned in your comment too....dunno why it's not behaving the same way as yours. It definitely snaps within the first section which is amazing, but the tracking is not as sharp as yours...really not sure why...
https://lisle.cargo.site/

Comment: Here is what u need to do https://imgur.com/a/ngtEFdF

Comment: Thank you brother!! =)))

Answer (score 0):

in the html file:

```
<div id="onMouseMove">....</div>
```

then on the jquery file:

```
$("#onMouseMove").on("mousemove", function(event) {....}
```

Comment: Hi and Welcome to SO. Even though your anwser might anwser the question, it can be considered low quality. An anwser should always contain a sufficient explaination of the issue aswell of your solution. This is important to understand the issue and your solution to make it reproduciable. Also it would always be good to include a code snippet (ctrl + m) to validate that your anwser would work. Please edit your anwser to meet the SO guidelines and contain the explanation and code snippet as mentioned above. As you're new to this site, I will not downvote your anwser.